# Align icon to left and text to center in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to align my icon to the left of a button view and the text to the center. Currently they are both aligned to the center but I am not sure how to get my icon on the very left edge of the button while keeping the text centered in the view

Right now my button looks like this:

[image]

I am using https://github.com/APSL/react-native-button for buttons and 
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons for icons

Below is some of my code:

```
    <Button style={signupStyles.facebookButton}>
      <View style={signupStyles.nestedButtonView}>
        <Icon
          name="facebook"
          size={30}
          color={'white'}

        />
        <Text style={signupStyles.buttonText}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
      </View>
    </Button>

    var signupStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonText: {
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },

    facebookButton: {
      backgroundColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
      borderColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 22,
    },

    nestedButtonView: {
     flexDirection: 'row',
     alignItems: 'center',
    },

  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That you can do by setting icon to a `width` and give text `padding-right`, `text-align` and `flex:1`

```
<Button style={signupStyles.facebookButton}>
  <View style={signupStyles.nestedButtonView}>
    <Icon
      name="facebook"
      size={30}
      color={'white'}
    />
    <Text style={signupStyles.buttonText}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
  </View>
</Button>

var signupStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

  facebookButton: {
    backgroundColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
    borderColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 22,
  },

  nestedButtonView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  iconLeft: {
    width: '40px',  
  },

  buttonText: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingRight: '40px',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with what seems like a bit of a hack. I added another icon to the right of the text and made it the same color as the background. I then gave my button text a flex of 2. If anyone has a better way I would love to know

```
    <Button style={signupStyles.facebookButton}>
      <View style={signupStyles.nestedButtonView}>
        <Icon
          name="facebook"
          size={30}
          color={"white"}
          style={signupStyles.iconLeft}
        />
        <Text style={signupStyles.buttonText}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
        <Icon
          name="facebook"
          size={30}
          color={styleConstants.facebookColor}
          style={signupStyles.iconRight}
        />
      </View>
    </Button>
```

styling:

```
buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    flex: 2
  },

  iconLeft: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },

  iconRight: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<Button style={signupStyles.facebookButton}>
      <View style={signupStyles.nestedButtonView}>
      <View style={signupStyles.iconstyle}>
        <Icon
          name="facebook"
          size={30}
          color={'white'}

        />
      </View>
        <Text style={signupStyles.buttonText}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
      </View>
    </Button>

var signupStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonText: {
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    iconstyle:{
   // alignItems:'flex-start'
    }

    facebookButton: {
      backgroundColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
      borderColor: styleConstants.facebookColor,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 22,
    },

    nestedButtonView: {
   //  flexDirection: 'row'
    },

  });
```