# React Native align icon left and text centered

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, touchablehighlight

I'm farily new to React Native, and I'm trying to do something very simple:

I want to create the following component:

A **TouchableHighlight** that has an image aligned to its left and text centered relative to the Touchable.

I've tried a bunch of options like adding padding or margin to the text but that just makes the button bigger and doesn't seem to be cleanest approach.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {}} style={styles.button}>
          <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
            <Image source={require('./assets/ic_logout.png')} style={styles.icon} />
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Log out</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#1d2aba',
    paddingHorizontal: 60,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  icon: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
    width: 25,
    height: 25
  },
  btnText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white'
  }
});

export default App;
```

**For visual purposes:**

[image: React Native]

Here's the **[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@franch/iconizedbutton)** for your testing desires!
**PS:** Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516352/align-icon-to-left-and-text-to-center-in-react-native) but to no avail.

Comment: Do you want to keep some space between your image and text?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh exactly! I want the image to be near the left border and the text in the middle of the button, thanks!

Comment: Kindly check my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh wow! spot on! thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you, dude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is you solution. Update the below style:

**For icon:**

```
icon: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 2, // Keep some space between your left border and Image
  },
```

**For Text:**

```
 btnText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white',
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%'
  }
```

You can update both style in your code and check.